# Writing a variable to file PHP

Tags: php

When I execute this:

```
$filename = "test.php";
$content = "<?php $variable = 35 ?>";
file_put_contents($filename,$content);
```

The file contains this:

```
<?php  =35?>
```

How can I get it to include the $variable ?

Also, how can I append this to the top of the file without overwriting existing data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes to prevent PHP from trying to interpolate `$variable`.

```
$content = '<?php $variable = 35 ?>';
```

Finally, you would append this to the file by using [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) and passing the `'a'` mode, which will append to the bottom of the file

To append to the top, it is a bit more complicated. As far as I know, you will have to read the entire file in and concatenate the old contents to the end of the new contents.